# Error: setting jQuery FullCalendar properties when the user changes the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to change the minTime property of agendaDay dinamically when the user changes the date. I've tryed this:

```
dayRender: function(event, element, view) {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options.minTime = '10:35:00';

          //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
}
```

The value '10:35:00' is only an example, because my application brings the real values from database according the selected date. When I uncomment the line `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');` the page becomes white in consequence of an error, I think.I've tried also `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');` with no results, and the same error appears. 
What is the correct manner to refresh the view when the user changes the date?

Answer (score 0):

After initialization is complete, you can only change 'contentHeight','height','aspectRatio',so you must destroy the calendar then rebuild